# Express matrix in more compact form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have the following sum:
$$
S = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n a_{jk} x_j^T B x_k
$$
where $x_j$ is a vector of length $m$, and $B$ is an $m \times m$ positive definite matrix, and $a_{jk}$ are positive scalars. I want to rewrite this sum as a symmetric bilinear form
$$
S = x^T C x
$$
where $x$ is a vector of length $nm$:
$$
x = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
\vdots \\
x_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $C$ is an $nm \times nm$ matrix. By writing out all the terms, I found that:
$$
C = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} B & a_{12} B & \dots & a_{1n} B \\
a_{21} B & a_{22} B & \dots & a_{2n} B \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} B & a_{n2} B & \dots & a_{nn} B
\end{pmatrix}
$$
My question is: **is there a way to express this matrix in a more elegant, compact form, using the matrix $A_{ij} = a_{ij}$ and $B$, without having to write out all the entries like above?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix $C$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) $C = A \otimes B$.